# Using custom tiles with the UWP MapControl

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary, uwp

So I'm attempting to show a custom map that's stored locally in my UWP app. For the moment, my code is:

```
MapZoomLevelRange range;
range.Min = 6;
range.Max = 8;
// Create a local data source.
LocalMapTileDataSource dataSource = new LocalMapTileDataSource("ms-appx:///MapTiles/{zoomlevel}/y{x}x{y}.png");
map.Center = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 5, Longitude = 5 });
// Create a tile source and add it to the Map control.
MapTileSource tileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource);
tileSource.ZoomLevelRange = range;
map.TileSources.Add(tileSource);
tileSource.Layer = MapTileLayer.BackgroundReplacement;
map.Style = MapStyle.None;
map.ZoomLevel = 7;
```

The minor problem I've got is that no map is appearing. How can I tell the MapControl that:

-The zoomlevel can't be larger than 8 or smaller than 6.

-For scale 8, My most south east tile has X=28 and Y=39

-For scale 7, My most south east tile has X=12 and Y=20

-For scale 6, My most south east tile has X=5 and Y=6

Comment: Hey! Did you find any solution? How did you generate tiles for your map? Thank you!